# Can't get all result of query in prolog

Tags: prolog

When I query remove_row([[r,r],[b,b]],A), it is supposed to get A of value [[e,e],[b,b]] and [[r,r],[e,e]], but I only get the fisrt value and the program get stuck

[image]

[image]

Comment: Copy-pasted code is preferred to images of code as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

```
empty_row([]).
empty_row([e|R]) :-
          empty_row(R).

remove_row([R1|B1], [R2|B2]) :-
    matching_row(R1),
    \+ empty_row(R1),
    same_length(R1, R2),    % <- I switched these two around
    empty_row(R2),          % <-
    B1 = B2.

remove_row([X|B1], [X|B2]) :-
    remove_row(B1, B2).
```

I switched the order of those two lines around, and now it works. It was a hunch; I don't understand why your version does not work. Tracing through your code to see what it's doing stops producing output, presumably in an infinite loop somewhere.

Backtracking over `empty_row(2)` it generates `[]`, `[e]`, `[e,e]` and it seems to me that should work. Apparently constraining the second list by length then allows it to fill a list of that length with `e`.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenient, here are my codes: same_length(L1,L2) :-
        length(L1,X),
        length(L2,Y),
        X = Y.

matching_row([]).
matching_row([_]).
matching_row([F,F|R]) :-
    matching_row([F|R]).

empty_row([]).
empty_row([e|R]) :-
        empty_row(R).


remove_row([R1|B1],[R2|B2]) :-
               matching_row(R1),
               \+empty_row(R1),
               same_length(R1,R2),
               empty_row(R2),
               B1 = B2.
remove_row([X|B1],[X|B2]) :-
               remove_row(B1,B2).

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally found the problem. I wrote the same_length function in this way :same_length(L1,L2) :-
        length(L1,X),
        length(L2,Y), X=Y. So the program will keep trying same_length like trying 2=3 then fail, 2=4 then fail and enter an infinite loop. So if I change the function to same_length(L1,L2) :-
        length(L1,X),
        length(L2,X), and also change the order of the two_line the program work. Thank you very much for helping.